# What does the expression "dig in" mean?

Tags: meaning

> *Anyone doing #laravel, #php or #MySQL Should probably check this out.  I can't wait **to dig in** myself*

In text above, what does the expression "to dig in" mean? I couldn't get it even looking at the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informal. Get involved, partake, consume, etc, eagerly, and maybe also, promptly. Originally mainly about food, but also may be applied to any attractive or exciting activity.

> 4. PHRASAL VERB
>
> If someone digs in, or digs into some food, they start eating eagerly.
> If you tell someone to dig in, you are inviting them to start eating,
> and encouraging them to eat as much as they want.

[Dig in (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dig-in)

Comment: Anyone who was under a certain age in Bristol, UK, in the 1970s and 1980s, and liked going to student/music night clubs, will remember one in a cellar, called the 'Dugout', whose slogan was 'Dig-in at the Dugout'.